# Errors is returning the number of words in a sentence

Tags: java

I am getting errors in my code when it returns the number of words in a sentence. I have a variable that holds what the sentence delimiters are. The text file I'm reading in is included below.
Thanks for any help.

Text being read in: "one!!!!! two!!!!! three: Baba? Oho! Bubu and bebe."

WORD_DELIMETERS =".:;?!,' ' ";

Output I'm receiving:

There are 9 words in the file.

There are 14 vowels in the file.

There are 6 sentences in the file.

It should be returning 8 words not 9, sentences and vowels are correct.

```
//START of count the words********************************************
int wordCounter= 0;
int last_Index=0;
for(int i=0;i<myFile.length()-1;i++){
     for(int j=0;j<WORD_DELIMETERS.length()-1;j++){
        if(myFile.charAt(i)==WORD_DELIMETERS.charAt(j)){
                if(myFile.charAt(i+1) !=' '){
                    if(last_Index!=i-1){
                        wordCounter++;
                    }
                    last_Index=i;

                }
            } 
       } 
}
// END of count the words***********************************************
```

Comment: Debug your code and you'll know why.

Comment: We're not here to do your homework for you. So, show that you're making an effort to solve the problem, then you'll get help.

Comment: Such complicated way to count words... Take a look at `String#split`.

Comment: Yes, You can use .split. This is easiest

Comment: If I use the default text I placed in the code it returns the proper values.'DEFAULT_STRING = "The big red dog, jumped lazily over the fence. The cow jumped over the moon!!!";' not sure where it's going wrong. If I place the default text in a file and read it in I get correct return values so I know it's not an error while reading in the file.

Comment: We are only allowed to use loops and we have to use the delimiters to sort out the number of occurrences of words, vowels, and sentences. Thanks

Comment: @m0skit0 Java has String.split :)

Comment: Please show your code completely, and what you want us to help you. The idea is easy, I don't know your point.

Comment: @barwnikk That's what I said, my dear.

Answer (score 0):

## You don't count first word. So, you must start counter from 1, if string isn't empty.

I use it:

```
    String myFile = "one!!!!! two!!!!! three: Baba? Oho! Bubu and bebe.";
    String pattern ="[.|:|;|?|!|,|'| ]";
    int counter = 0;
    for(String word : myFile.split(pattern)) {
        if(word.length()!=0)counter++;
    }
    System.out.println("Words: "+counter); //print Words: 8
```

You can edit your counter to:

```
public static int yourCounter(String myFile) {
    if(myFile.length()==0)return 0;
    String WORD_DELIMETERS = ".:;?!,' ]";
    int wordCounter= WORD_DELIMETERS.contains(myFile.charAt(0)+"")?0:1;
    int last_Index=0;
    for(int i=0;i<myFile.length()-1;i++){
         for(int j=0;j<WORD_DELIMETERS.length()-1;j++){
            if(myFile.charAt(i)==WORD_DELIMETERS.charAt(j)){
                    if(myFile.charAt(i+1) !=' '){
                        if(last_Index!=i-1){
                            wordCounter++;
                        }
                        last_Index=i;

                    }
                } 
           } 
    }
    return wordCounter;
}
```

I use a split and regex. Look below:
Sample on long text:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Throwable {
    String text = "Java is a computer programming langua"
            + "ge that is concurrent, class-based, objec"
            + "t-oriented, and specifically designed to "
            + "have as few implementation dependencies a"
            + "s possible. It is intended to let applica"
            + "tion developers \"write once, run anywher"
            + "e\" (WORA), meaning that code that runs o"
            + "n one platform does not need to be recomp"
            + "iled to run on another. Java applications"
            + " are typically compiled to bytecode (clas"
            + "s file) that can run on any Java virtual "
            + "machine (JVM) regardless of computer arch"
            + "itecture. Java is, as of 2012, one of the"
            + " most popular programming languages in us"
            + "e, particularly for client-server web app"
            + "lications, with a reported 9 million deve"
            + "lopers.[10][11] Java was originally devel"
            + "oped by James Gosling at Sun Microsystems"
            + " (which has since merged into Oracle Corp"
            + "oration) and released in 1995 as a core c"
            + "omponent of Sun Microsystems' Java platfo"
            + "rm. The language derives much of its synt"
            + "ax from C and C++, but it has fewer low-l"
            + "evel facilities than either of them. The "
            + "original and reference implementation Jav"
            + "a compilers, virtual machines, and class "
            + "libraries were developed by Sun from 1991"
            + " and first released in 1995. As of May 20"
            + "07, in compliance with the specifications"
            + " of the Java Community Process, Sun relic"
            + "ensed most of its Java technologies under"
            + " the GNU General Public License. Others h"
            + "ave also developed alternative implementa"
            + "tions of these Sun technologies, such as "
            + "the GNU Compiler for Java (bytecode compi"
            + "ler), GNU Classpath (standard libraries),"
            + " and IcedTea-Web (browser plugin for appl"
            + "ets).";
    System.out.println("Text:\n"+text+"\n--------------------\nWords: "+countWords(text) + "\nSentecens: " + countSentecens(text)
            + "\nVowels: " + countVowels(text) + "\nChars: "
            + text.toCharArray().length + "\nUpper cases: "
            + countUpperCases(text)+"\nYour counter of words: "+yourCounter(text));
}


public static int yourCounter(String myFile) {
    if(myFile.length()==0)return 0;
    String WORD_DELIMETERS = ".:;?!,' ]";
    int wordCounter= WORD_DELIMETERS.contains(myFile.charAt(0)+"")?0:1;
    int last_Index=0;
    for(int i=0;i<myFile.length()-1;i++){
         for(int j=0;j<WORD_DELIMETERS.length()-1;j++){
            if(myFile.charAt(i)==WORD_DELIMETERS.charAt(j)){
                    if(myFile.charAt(i+1) !=' '){
                        if(last_Index!=i-1){
                            wordCounter++;
                        }
                        last_Index=i;

                    }
                } 
           } 
    }
    return wordCounter;
}

public static int countUpperCases(String text) {
    int upper = 0;
    char[] compare1 = text.toCharArray();
    char[] compare2 = text.toUpperCase().toCharArray();
    for (int i = 0; i < compare1.length; i++) {
        if (compare1[i] != compare2[i])
            upper++;
    }
    return upper;
}

public static int countWords(String text) {
    String pattern = "[.|:|;|?|!|,|'| ]";
    int counter = 0;
    for (String word : text.split(pattern)) {
        if (word.length() != 0)
            counter++;
    }
    return counter;
}

public static int countSentecens(String text) {
    String pattern = "[.|?|!]";
    int counter = 0;
    for (String word : text.split(pattern)) {
        if (word.length() != 0)
            counter++;
    }
    return counter;

}

public static int countVowels(String text) {
    int vowels = 0;
    for (char c : text.toCharArray()) {
        switch (c) {
        case 'a':
            vowels++;
        case 'e':
            vowels++;
        case 'i':
            vowels++;
        case 'o':
            vowels++;
        case 'u':
            vowels++;
        }
    }
    return vowels;
}
```

## This return:

Text:

Java is a computer programming language that is concurrent, class-based, object-oriented, and specifically designed to have as few implementation dependencies as possible. It is intended to let application developers "write once, run anywhere" (WORA), meaning that code that runs on one platform does not need to be recompiled to run on another. Java applications are typically compiled to bytecode (class file) that can run on any Java virtual machine (JVM) regardless of computer architecture. Java is, as of 2012, one of the most popular programming languages in use, particularly for client-server web applications, with a reported 9 million developers.[10][11] Java was originally developed by James Gosling at Sun Microsystems (which has since merged into Oracle Corporation) and released in 1995 as a core component of Sun Microsystems' Java platform. The language derives much of its syntax from C and C++, but it has fewer low-level facilities than either of them. The original and reference implementation Java compilers, virtual machines, and class libraries were developed by Sun from 1991 and first released in 1995. As of May 2007, in compliance with the specifications of the Java Community Process, Sun relicensed most of its Java technologies under the GNU General Public License. Others have also developed alternative implementations of these Sun technologies, such as the GNU Compiler for Java (bytecode compiler), GNU Classpath (standard libraries), and IcedTea-Web (browser plugin for applets).

---

Words: 230

Sentecens: 9

Vowels: 1597

Chars: 1516

Upper cases: 1154

Your counter of words: 230

Answer (score 0):

You only need one line:

```
int words = myFile.split("[" + WORD_DELIMETERS + "]+").length;
```

This uses regex to nearly split the input into words, which are then counted by using the length of the array. Multiple consecutive delimiters are treated as a single delimiter by adding the plus sign after the character class, so "one!!!!two!!!" counts as two words.